# How to hide div based on select the dropdown in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to hide div based on select the dropdown.
Here is the sample code I have written

```
 <div>
                    <p>Course Type</p>
                    <div>
                        <select name="student-type" id="student-type" class="icon-select-down" ng-model="studentType" ng-change="getOption(this)">
                            <option value="java" selected>Java</option>
                            <option value="angularjs">Angular js</option>
                            <option value="reactJs">React js</option>
                        </select> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div ng-if="studentType">
                  <p>Attendence Days</p>
                  <div class="slice-item">
                    <input type="text" class="input input-text" ng-model="attendenceDays" required validate-on="blur" ng-pattern="/^([1-9]|10)$/" invalid-message="'You must enter number between 1 to 25'" />
                  </div>
                </div>
```

In controller i have written below code.

```
$scope.getOption = function(value) {
                     if (value.studentType = "angularjs") {
                       $scope.studentType = "false";
                     }
                    };
```

Can any one please guide me solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is the issue with your code?**

Its purely the logical issue. You are checking `ng-if="studentType"` for showing the input container. Inside the change event you are using `if (value.studentType = "angularjs")`. This is not a condition checking, its assignment opertator. You have to use `if (value.studentType == "angularjs")` or `if (value.studentType === "angularjs")` to compare the value `value.studentType` with string `"angularjs"`. In your scenario, the if statement will always assign `"angularjs"` to `studentType` and after that the code inside if will assign `"false"` to `studentType`. There is no need to do this in this way.

You could do this in multiple ways. I suggest two options here

- **Option 1**: Inside the template check the value for `studentType`. If `studentType` is not `angularjs` then only display the input. So just add a condition in `ng-if="studentType !== 'angularjs'"`. Here you dont have to write any logic inside the controller

**Working Fiddle**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    // $scope.showInput = true;
    // $scope.getOption = function (value) {
    //     if (value.studentType == "angularjs") {
    //         $scope.showInput = false;
    //     }
    // };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
        <p>Course Type</p>
        <div>
            <select name="student-type" id="student-type" class="icon-select-down" ng-model="studentType"
                ng-change="getOption(this)">
                <option value="java" selected>Java</option>
                <option value="angularjs">Angular js</option>
                <option value="reactJs">React js</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="studentType !== 'angularjs'">
        <p>Attendence Days</p>
        <div class="slice-item">
            <input type="text" class="input input-text" ng-model="attendenceDays" required validate-on="blur"
                ng-pattern="/^([1-9]|10)$/" invalid-message="'You must enter number between 1 to 25'" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- **Option 2**: Inside the change function, check the value of selected option. Set a visiblity boolean based on the value of selected option. Make the input visible based on that boolean

**Working Fiddle**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showInput = true;
    $scope.getOption = function (value) {
        $scope.showInput = value.studentType !== "angularjs";
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
        <p>Course Type</p>
        <div>
            <select name="student-type" id="student-type" class="icon-select-down" ng-model="studentType"
                ng-change="getOption(this)">
                <option value="java" selected>Java</option>
                <option value="angularjs">Angular js</option>
                <option value="reactJs">React js</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="showInput">
        <p>Attendence Days</p>
        <div class="slice-item">
            <input type="text" class="input input-text" ng-model="attendenceDays" required validate-on="blur"
                ng-pattern="/^([1-9]|10)$/" invalid-message="'You must enter number between 1 to 25'" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```